# Android Studio - automatic project load

Tags: android-studio, project, loading

I cannot find a way to prevent Android Studio from automatically loading the last project in use. I want it open me the beggining window with the list of projects available and not loading the last used automatically.

Comment: Accept the answer if that works for you.

Comment: This is the worst design yet again brought to us by Google. Automatic project open as if they know what's better for us. Why not also develop an Automagic Programming so Android Studio would make app for us automagically? Make everything on this IDE automatic. That sounds fun!

Comment: I wish I  could start AS without opening a project at all. I update studio when I'm not in the middle of a project (don't want to chance an update breaking what's due in the next hour!). Opening a project to open studio to apply updates is tedious and time consuming

Comment: Yeah, it's one of the most stupid default behaviors I've seen in my entire IT career. What the hell Google developers were thinking when setting this behavior as the default?

Comment: In 2020 still agree. Not sure if there is work around today, but don't see one. I end up choosing a smaller project to minimize the load time. Sigh....

Answer (score 95):

The location of `Reopen last project on startup` was moved to `Settings` => `Appearance & Behavior` => `System Settings` with new Android Studio, just uncheck it!

Answer (score 45):

In **Appearance & Behavior -> System Setting** , also you can change some other setting about open or save projects

Android Studio 2.1.1 MacOS X

**UPDATE**

This screen can accessed in Android Studio 3.1.3 on MacOS High Sierra by selecting the **Android Studio -> Preferences** menu

[image: Screenshot Android Studio 2.1.1 MacOSX]

Comment: An update: This screen can accessed in Android Studio 3.1.3 on macOs High Sierra  by selecting the `Android Studio -> Preferences` menu (Near to the Apple logo). Updated the original post as well

Comment: @sunil please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text

Comment: @Zoe I was not aware about this. Thanks for letting me know. However, there should be a way the sections in the post be identifiable to readers. You could have used **Bold** instead of removing **Code** sections

Comment: I love descriptive Screenshots. Kudos for that!

Answer (score 16):

**Android Studio** or **Intellij IDEA**:

From the menu go to :

`File` > `Settings >Appearence & Behavior` > `System Settings`.

disable the option:

**`Reopen last project on startup`**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 6):

Open `Settings`, go to `General` and remove check from `Reopen last project on startup`

Answer (score 1):

If the project that is being reopened is causing android studio to stop responding you may not be able to get to the dialog. I got round this by deleting

```
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.3/options/recentProjects.xml
```

This allowed me to temporarily start android studio without reopening the offending project, and then permanently disable the reopening feature using the dialog others have mentioned

Comment: I had the same issue, but on windows. For those who's having the same problem, the windows path should be similar as follow: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\options\recentProjects.xml

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on MacOS when I added Android Studio Canary and Intellij. I'm not sure which caused the issue.

Anyway, here's the steps that I used to fix it:

1. Open Android Studio to see what project it opens; write down that project.
2. It will freeze, so you need to force quit it.
3. Erase the nodes where that project name exists. For me it was the last `<entry>` element and the `<option>` element in the ***recentProjects.xml*** file (location below). **Make sure you delete the complete element!**
4. Restart and it should work. Otherwise, repeat for the new recently opened project that is freezing Android Studio.

Where is the file?

- ***~Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/options***

It took me digging up [the location of Intellij files](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs?page=2) then back tracking it to Google then Android Studio to find where the file exists. I hope I save someone the time I wasted on this. :D

Extra note:

The `<entry>` node is in here:

```
<application>
  <component name="RecentProjectsManager">
    <option name="additionalInfo">
      <map>
```