# How can I prevent Android Studio from opening last project?

Tags: android-studio

Everytime I initialize Android Studio it launches with the last opened project *automatically*.

How can I stop this?

Comment: I think that it is duplicate of an other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646010/android-studio-automatic-project-load

Answer (score 178, accepted):

If you go to *File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings*
then you have a checkbox **Reopen last project on startup**.

This is at least in Android Studio 1.2.1.1, on Windows 7.

Comment: So funny... but TY. Works on Mac :P

Comment: Very similar on Mac, from menu bar: Android Studio | Preferences | System Settings, then uncheck "Reopen last project on startup".

Comment: I think this is the first thing most people do after installing android studio or IntelliJ.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without opening Android studio, I have a disc that is being scanned right now, and I'd rather see the project dialog so I can select a project in another location, so that it does not mess with the scan or the files on that drive.